# Word that means to buy and cease operations

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes the behaviour of some large companies to buy another company with only the intent to cease operations of the company. Example usage: This company is infamous for their (word) of other companies.

Comment: to 'acquire' and 'with intent to close'  oops 5 words!

Comment: Food-related words and phrases like “devouring” and “gobbling up” may get the idea across.

Comment: 'Asset-stripping' is the term applied to company takeovers which are acquisitive, that is to say they have the sole intention of seizing assets rather than the prosperity of the entity of the company as an entirety. But they do not -necessarily - end in company closure, which makes your question difficult to answer, so this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: A related term (though not exactly what you're asking for) is "[embrace, extend, extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)".

Comment: The term "catch and kill" has been appearing recently in relation to the Trump-Daniels affair, referring to the journalistic practice of purchasing exclusive rights to a story with no intention of publishing it - the real goal being its suppression.  It occurred to me that this term might also be applied in the sense you want, but a brief google suggests that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know there is no term for precisely this practise, because shutting down another company ("*with **only** the intent*" of ceasing its operations) is not in itself a very good reason for undertaking the expense of purchasing it. Ordinarily, a purchaser seeks to acquire the company's assets, and shutting down the company is typically incidental to a larger strategy of spinning off liabilities—leaving the liabilities with the acquired company, which now declares bankruptcy and imposes the economic loss on the creditors rather than the acquirer.

I think your best bet here is ***asset-stripping***. The term is usually applied to purchasers who auction off the assets acquired rather than merging them into their own operations; but that's a finer distinction than you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there may not be one term that specifies exactly what you are describing.  It is, however, one version of what is termed a "corporate raid".  As described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_raid), it is taking over a company for a purpose counter to the wants and goals of its current management, sometimes "liquidating the company."

Not that I would particularly recommend seeing the movie, but if you did happen to see *Pretty Woman*, the character Edward Lewis is a "corporate raider" who specializes in doing just that.

So, depending on how much malice you want to add to the term, "raid and liquidate", "raid and ravage", "raid and annihilate" or other [synonym for "take apart"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/take%20apart).

Answer (score 0):

The term **predation** might convey the general idea, but it clearly doesn't address the specific goal of suppressing a competitor.

> Merriam-Webster:
>
> [Predation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predation)
>
> 2 : the act of injuring, exploiting, or plundering others for personal gain

Answer (score -1):

***Closure*** fits the general description when used in the business context. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(business)),

> Closure is the term used to refer to the actions necessary when it is no longer necessary or possible for a business or other organization to continue to operate. Closure may be the result of a bankruptcy, (...) as a result of **a business being purchased by another organization (or a competitor) and shut down** as superfluous, or because it is the non-surviving entity in a corporate merger.

If you want to be very specific then there are [many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22purchase+and+closure%22+business&client=firefox) on Google search of the use of the term "**purchase and closure**".